# sed replace PATH in .bashrc

Tags: sed

I have the following entry in my `.bashrc`:

```
PATH=$PATH:/home/user/abc/bin;export PATH; # ADDED BY INSTALLER - DO NOT EDIT OR DELETE THIS COMMENT
```

I want to substitute `/home/user/abc/bin` for any path that I choose. How can I do this with `sed`?

I have the following:

```
sed 's,PATH=[^;]*,PATH=$PATH/home/user/app/2.1,' -i ~/.bashrc
```

But, this will substitute anything that begins with `PATH`, how can I specify to only select what begins with `PATH` but also includes the string `ADDED BY INSTALLER - DO NOT EDIT OR DELETE THIS COMMENT`

Comment: Why use `sed` for one entry? Do you need to do it multiple times?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You do so:

```
NEWPATH="your_new_path" sed -i "/ADDED BY INSTALLER - DO NOT EDIT OR DELETE THIS COMMENT/ s:/home/user/abc/bin:$NEWPATH:" .bashrc
```

Answer (score 0):

With anchors to the beginning (`^`) and end of line (`$`), like this:

```
sed -i.bak -e 's,^PATH=[^;]*\(.*ADDED BY INSTALLER - DO NOT EDIT OR DELETE THIS COMMENT\)$,PATH=$PATH/home/user/app/2.1\1,' ~/.bashrc
```

I've added the `.bak` suffix to the in-place edit, for security.